# How to fix function for deleting element from stack?

Tags: c, stack

I try to create function that will get some stack with integer numbers and "n" (number for deleting). The function will check the stack and delete the element if find him. The stack need to stay in same order after deleting the "n" element. I try to copy all elements to temporary stack and when find the element not to copy him. After that I want to return all elements to first stack. Something is wrong in my function. I build my function around some code, that I found in the net.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 3
typedef int item;

typedef struct
{
    int TOP;
    int ele[MAX];
}Stack;

void init(Stack* s)
{
    s->TOP = -1;
}

int isFull(Stack* s)
{
    if (s->TOP == MAX - 1)
        return 0;
    return -1;
}

int isEmpty(Stack* s)
{
    if (s->TOP == -1)
        return 0;
    return -1;
}

void push(Stack* s, int item)
{
    if (!isFull(s))
    {
        printf("\nStack is full");
        return;
    }
    s->TOP = s->TOP + 1;
    s->ele[s->TOP] = item;
}

int pop(Stack* s, int* item)
{
    if (!isEmpty(s))
    {
        printf("\nStack is empty");
        return -1;
    }
    *item = s->ele[s->TOP];
    s->TOP = s->TOP - 1;

    return 0;
}

void func(Stack* s, item num)
{
    //Check stack
    if (s->TOP == -1)
    {
        printf_s("is empty");
        return 0;
    }       

    Stack temp;      //def temporary stack
    init(&temp);     //init temporary stack
    item current=0;

    while (s->TOP != -1)
    {       
        pop(&s, &current);
        if (current != num)
        {
            push(&temp, current);
        }           
    }

    while (!isEmpty(&temp))
    {
         pop(&temp, &current);
         push(&s, current);
    }

    while (s->TOP != -1)
    {
        pop(&s, &current);
        {
            printf_s("\nPoped Item : %d", current);
        }   
    }
}

int main()
{
    Stack s;
    item num = 20;

    init(&s);

    push(&s, 4);
    push(&s, 20);
    push(&s, 11);

    func(&s, num);    //delete specific element in stack

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to fix all moments, but all the same warnings appear ... and the code does not work. ==>>> New version:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 3
typedef int item;

typedef struct
{
    int top;
    int ele[MAX];
}Stack;

void init(Stack* s)
{
    s->top = -1;
}

int isFull(Stack* s)
{
    return s->top == MAX - 1;
}

int isEmpty(Stack* s)
{
    return s->top != -1;
}

void push(Stack* s, int item)
{
    if (isFull(s))
    {
        printf("\nStack is full");
        return;
    }
    ++s->top;         //can be written as: s->TOP = s->TOP + 1;
    s->ele[s->top] = item;
}

int pop(Stack* s, int* item)
{
    if (!isEmpty(s))
    {
        printf("\nStack is empty");
        return -1;
    }
    *item = s->ele[s->top];
    --s->top;        //can be written as: s->top = s->top - 1;

    return 0;
}

void func(Stack* s, item num)
{
    //Check stack
    if (s->top == -1)
    {
        printf_s("is empty");
        return;
    }

    Stack temp;      //def temporary stack
    init(&temp);     //init temporary stack
    item current = 0;

    while (s->top != -1)
    {
        pop(s, &current);
        if (current != num)
        {
            push(&temp, current);
        }
    }

    while (!isEmpty(&temp))
    {
        pop(&temp, &current);
        push(s, current);
    }

    while (s->top != -1)
    {
        pop(&s, &current);
        {
            printf_s("\nPoped Item : %d", current);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    Stack s;
    item num = 20;

    init(&s);

    push(&s, 4);
    push(&s, 20);
    push(&s, 11);

    func(&s, num);    //delete specific element in stack

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does your `void func(Stack *s, int item)` returning `int` values within somehow *not* generate at least warnings when you compile? And `pop` takes a `Stack *` as the first argument, right? so in `func` the code `pop(&s, &current);`, where `s` is already `Stack *`, therefore sending a `Stack **` as the first argument? That too  didn't flag any warnings? Short version: *turn on your warnings and treat them as errors*.

Comment: Tip: `s->TOP = s->TOP + 1;` can be written as `++s->Top;`

Comment: Tip: `s->TOP = s->TOP - 1;` can be written as `--s->Top;`

Comment: Tip: `1` is more commonly used for true than `-1`.

Comment: Tip: `if (s->TOP == -1) return 0; return 1;` can be written as `return s->TOP != -1;`

Comment: `isFull` doesn't do what its name says it does. It should be `int isFull(Stack* s) { return s->TOP == MAX - 1; }` (and `push` should use `if (isFull(s))` instead of `if (!isFull(s))`).

Comment: Tip: Be more consistent. In some places, you use `!isEmpty(&s)`. In others, you use `s->TOP != -1`. These both do the same thing!

Comment: Related to your code: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/381711/283695

Comment: Thank you all for your help.  I will check my code again and report the results.

Comment: Hint: `int TOP;` : dont use all capital identifiers, this is unusual. Normally all capitals identifiers are used for macros by convention. This is not related to your problem though

Comment: You need to write a function which takes an array and an element. Then remove the element from the array by copying the `n + 1` th element to the `n` th element until the end of the array is reached. `n` is of course the element you want to delete.

Comment: I tried to fix all moments, but all the same warnings appear ... and the code does not work. I added new version of code in my question--^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
    pop(&s, &current);
```

`s` is already a pointer. It is defined as `Stack * s`. Therefore `&s` is a `Stack **`, whereas `pop` expects `Stack *` as the first parameter. Just remove `&` here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all users who help me with hints and tips! Here is final version after all corrections. Finally it works!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 7
typedef int item;

typedef struct
{
    int top;
    int ele[MAX];
}Stack;

void init(Stack* s)
{
    s->top = -1;
}

int isFull(Stack* s)
{
    return s->top == MAX - 1;
}

int isEmpty(Stack* s)
{
    return s->top == -1;
}

void push(Stack* s, int item)
{
    if (isFull(s))
    {
        printf("\nStack is full");
        return;
    }
    ++s->top;         //can be written as: s->TOP = s->TOP + 1;
    s->ele[s->top] = item;
}

int pop(Stack* s, int* item)
{
    if (isEmpty(s) == 1)
    {
        printf("\nStack is empty");
        return -1;
    }
    *item = s->ele[s->top];
    --s->top;        //can be written as: s->top = s->top - 1;

    return 0;
}

void func(Stack* s, item num)
{
    //Check stack
    if (isEmpty(s) == 1)
    {
        printf_s("is empty");
        return;
    }

    Stack temp;      //def temporary stack
    init(&temp);     //init temporary stack
    item current;

    printf_s("\n\nCopy all items from s stack to temp stack");
    while (isEmpty(s) != 1)
    {
        pop(s, &current);
        if (current != num)
        {
            push(&temp, current);
            printf_s("\nPushed Item is: %d", current);
        }
        else
            printf_s("\nDeleted Item is: %d", current);
    }

    printf_s("\n\n\nCopy all items from temp stack to s stack");

    while (isEmpty(&temp) != 1)
    {
        pop(&temp, &current);
        printf_s("\nPoped Item is: %d", current);
        push(s, current);
    }

    printf_s("\n\n\nPosition of elements in s stack");

    while (isEmpty(s) != 1)
    {
        pop(s, &current);
        printf_s("\nPoped Item is: %d", current);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Stack s;
    item stackElem;
    item num = 20;

    init(&s);

    printf("Fill stack \'s\'\n"); 
    while (!isFull(&s))
    {
        printf_s("Enter integer number please: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &stackElem);
        push(&s, stackElem);
        printf_s("Pushed Item is: %d\n", stackElem);
    }

    func(&s, num);    //delete specific element in stack

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

[image]